# What city am I supposed to be travelling to next?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, sports

I'm currently on a trip around the United States (for pleasure) and am a little lost. I had it all planned out but lost my itinerary somewhere along the way. Thought maybe you could help.

I started my journey in Baltimore, MD where I caught a baseball game before I took a plane ride that had a layover in Rochester, NY. I ended up staying there for 1 night before catching my connecting flight to Virginia Beach, VA. It was nice to see the ocean, but I could only stay there for 2 days before I had to fly out to Shreveport, LA. Now I am at the bus station and know I need to buy a ticket for the next leg of my trip, but for the life of me I can't remember where I am supposed to be going next.

What city am I supposed to be going to next?

Hint:

> The starting event sets the tone of the trip.

Another Hint:

> Why didn't I say how long I stayed in Shreveport?

How about another hint:

> D42s th3s h3nt h2lp y45 1t 1ll?

Another hint:

> I could have started my trip in many cities such as Birmingham, AL or Boston, MA or Baton Rouge, LA.

Probably last hint:

> First letters are key, but where are the vowels?

Comment: I lived in Rochester, NY for over 20 years, and haven't lived there in over 20 years. I was sure I would get this one. Damn!

Answer (score 8):

You start at:

> The stadium of the [Baltimore Orioles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baltimore_Orioles).

Then:

> You go to the Martin State Airport and take the plane and go to Rochester.

This is a:

> Nearly 90 degree anti-clockwise turn at the airport.

And Rochester is:

> the home of the [Rochester Red Wings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rochester_Red_Wings), which had a history with the Orioles.

Then at Rochester:

> You take a nearly 180 degrees turn and go to Virginia Beach.

Exactly at:

> Naval Air Station Oceana Airport

And there, you'll find:

> The [Virginia Beach Neptunes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virginia_Beach_Neptunes).

Where you:

> Take a nearly 270 degrees turn anti-clockwise (i.e. 90 degrees clockwise).

Which leads you to:

> Baskdale Air Force Base, at Bossier City LA, near Shreveport.

And then:

> You take a 360 degrees turn (i.e. continues going straight on).

Leading you to:

> Shreveport bus station.

And there, you will find:

> The [Shreveport-Bossier Captains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shreveport-Bossier_Captains).

Then you turn:

> 450 degrees (i.e. 90 degrees) anti-clockwise.

Which leads you to:

> Texarkana, Texas.

Which is:

> Home of the Texarkana Twins.

Comment: Extremely well researched, however wrong. I will say your starting point was correct :)  Rot13(Ba gur evtug genpx jvgu xrrcvat onfronyy ba gur zvaq)